# Page swapping ReactJS Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm making pagination and I want to implement following logic:Lets say last page is 2,If everything within second page will be deleted it shall automatically go to the first page.

I'm trying to check index of the last item on the page and if it will be deleted,function will change my page to the previous one.

The problem is I don't know how to check if item on that index is deleted.

Minimum amount of items on per page is 10

Any suggestions?

```
export const previousPage = (item) => {
return {
    type:actionTypes.PREVIOUS_PAGE,
    item
}
```

Reducer code:

```
    case actionTypes.PREVIOUS_PAGE:
        const indexOflastPageLastItem =  todos.length - 9
        const findWhichItemIsLastOnCurrentPage = todos.map(item => item.index === indexOflastPageLastItem)
        return {
            ...state,
            currentPage: action.item
        }
```

Comment: what about if you check item count after every delete and if itemCount/10 < currentPage set current page to previous one?

Comment: Nice once,I will try that

Comment: itemCount shall be length of the array right?

Comment: Yes. Whatever you listing on pages. But dont forget to ceil itemCount/10.